# Вывести html в следующий блок

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет, получаю данные в html с другой страницы через ajax

```
    $('.name-mod').click(function(){
    var mod_id = $(this).data('mod');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mod_info.php',
        data: 'mod_id='+mod_id,
        success: function(data){
            $('.content-mod').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Вопрос: как вывести данные в .content-mod по отношению к .name-mod, который располагается следующим,  при том что .name-mod тоже несколько?
(.content-mod на странице множество, выводить нужно только в следующий)
Пробовал `$(this).next('.content-mod').html(data);`

Comment: Следующий по отношению к чему?

Comment: По отношению к .name-mod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` внутри ajax `success` обработчика это не `this` внутри `click`:

```
$('.name-mod').click(function(){
  var mod_id = $(this).data('mod');
  var thisNameMod = this;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mod_info.php',
    data: 'mod_id='+mod_id,
    success: function(data){
      $(thisNameMod).next('.content-mod').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```